# Is there a way to load image from firestore in flutter?

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I'm a newbie to flutter so, i have been trying to load an image in flutter using cachenetworkimage and firestore but im unable to...and here's my code

Here's a quickview from firestore.

[image]

```
class _Home extends State<Home> {
  Future<RemoteConfig> remoteConfig() async => await RemoteConfig.instance;
   StreamSubscription<QuerySnapshot> subscription;
  List<DocumentSnapshot> wallpapersList;
  final CollectionReference collectionReference = Firestore.instance.collection("images").document('IQlIiQtlWaidilQKFw2Y') as CollectionReference;
   @override    
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
     subscription = collectionReference.snapshots().listen((datasnapshot) {
      setState(() {
    wallpapersList = datasnapshot.documents;
  });
});
}
List<Widget> ListMyWidgets() {
 List<Widget> list = new List();
 var wallpaperList;
  for(var i = 0; i< wallpaperList.length; i++){
    list.add(CachedNetworkImage(imageUrl: wallpaperList[i]['homescreen_bannersrc']));
 }
 return list;
}
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext ctx) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          Expanded(
            child: SingleChildScrollView(
              child: Container(
                child: Column(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
                  children: 
                  ListMyWidgets()
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Have you checked if print(snapshot.data['homescreen_bannersrc']) displaying your img url properly in the console?

Comment: No, it's not displaying it's throwing an exception.

Comment: I think snapshot.data returning array & you are trying to get ['homescreen_bannersrc'] from that array. Just try this print(snapshot.data); If it's showing an array then you need to iterate the array.

Comment: when I try to print(snapshot.data) this is showing up 
```Another exception was thrown: type 'QuerySnapshot' is not a subtype of type 'String'```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, your widget should be stateful as it seems you are not using anything to remember the state.

Then declare the following in your widget:

```
 StreamSubscription<QuerySnapshot> subscription;
 List<DocumentSnapshot> wallpapersList;
 final CollectionReference collectionReference =
      Firestore.instance.collection("images");
```

In initState add follwoing code:

```
subscription = collectionReference.snapshots().listen((datasnapshot) {
  setState(() {
    wallpapersList = datasnapshot.documents;
  });
});
```

Create the List of widgets now:

```
List<Widget> ListMyWidgets() {
 List<Widget> list = new List();
 for(var i = 0; i< wallpaperList.length; i++){
    list.add(CachedNetworkImage(imageUrl: wallpaperList[i]['homescreen_bannersrc']));
 }
 return list;
}
```

Now add the following code to build method:

```
Column(
 crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
 children: ListMyWidgets()
)
```

Comment: I don't want to show it in a list I just want to show only that one image. I updated my question please take a look. It's like i want to load the image in imageview string from firestore.

Comment: So instead of Firestore.instance.collection('images').getDocuments(). Try Firestore.instance.collection('images').document('IQlIiQtlWaidilQKFw2Y');